# Conditional replacement depending on other column value

Tags: sql, replace, conditional-statements

I have a database with a table containing:

```
********************************
* Code  *      FileName        *
********************************
* NULL  * Cats and Dogs        *
* C123  * C123 - Cats and Dogs *
* NULL  * Baking Cakes         *
* Z345  * Z345 - Plants        *
* F967  * E345 - Tractors      *
********************************
```

I'd like to return the filename or a manipulated filename for all rows, based on if there is a value in the code column and it matches with the code in the filename.

So the query should return

```
Cats and Dogs
xxxx - Cats and Dogs
Baking Cakes
xxxx - Plants
E345 - Tractors
```

From the above set of data.

I'm struggling with doing a conditional replace on a value from another column - if I did it with a case statement I'd need to list all of the possible codes, which would be difficult to maintain. Is there any way to do

```
Select Replace(FileName, Code, "xxxx") from table where filename like %Code%
```

Comment: What is wrong with the query you wrote?  That looks very close to what might work for you here.  Of course, the best answer would be to a regex replacement, but SQL Server does not support this out of the box.

Comment: I think I was overthinking this one - but this specifically didn't return the values which didn't have a code. The other responses with the case statements are what I needed!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may try the following query:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN Code IS NULL
         THEN FileName
         ELSE REPLACE(FileName, Code + ' - ', 'xxxx - ') END AS label
FROM yourTable;
```

[image]

### Demo

You don't necessarily need a `WHERE` clause here, since the replacement logic already checks if there be a match.  Note that I search for `code  -`, i.e. the code in the context in which you expect it.  The alleviates, at least partially, the chance that there could be a false replacement.

Comment: The user wants to result set from his post, I screen shot it in my answer

Comment: Thanks for this - The correct use of the Case statement to get what I needed did the trick - although I didn't need the extra search for -

Marking this one as the solution over the other one with CHARINDEX as it seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp (Code varchar(25), FileName varchar (25))

INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES
(NULL, 'Cats and Dogs '),
('C123', 'C123 - Cats and Dogs'),
(NULL, 'Baking Cakes'),
('Z345', 'Z345 - Plants'),
('F967', 'E345 - Tractors')

SELECT  
CASE 
      WHEN CHARINDEX(Code, FileName,1)>0 THEN Replace(FileName, Code, 'xxxx') 
      ELSE FileName 
END As Result
FROM #tmp
```

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't phrase the replacement using `CHARINDEX`.  There is nothing wrong with doing a blanket replacement, except for the fact the code might be `NULL`.  So I think you should be checking for `NULL` codes.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not? If Code=NULL wouldnt char index =0? And furthermore if code & filename = NULL would the replacement just be sending back the correct output (which would be null)? Feel free to explain :)

Comment: The replace function already implicitly only does something if it finds the substring in the target.  So calling `CHARINDEX` seems superfluous to me.